# XPath expression for parsing HTML - partially wildcard expression

Tags: php, html, xpath

I'm using XPath expressions to extract some values from a website. I.e.:

```
$res = $xp2->evaluate('//th[.="Imiona"]/following-sibling::*[1][name()="td"]');
```

But when I try to make an expression that contains special (Polish) characters, it does not work:

```
$res = $xp2->evaluate('//th[.="Funkcja w organie zarządzającym"]/following-sibling::*[1][name()="td"]');
```

How can I rewrite this expression to avoid special characters? I.e. How can I search for `TH` elements that contain a text starting with "Funkcja w organie"? I tried something like this:

```
$res = $xp2->evaluate('//th[.="Funkcja w organie *"]/following-sibling::*[1][name()="td"]');
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Are you sure you got the encoding of the source code right?

Comment: No, I'm not, the encoding is mostly unpredictable. That's why I want to avoid special chars in my expressions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `starts-with()`:

```
$res = $xp2->query('//th[starts-with(text(), "Funkcja w organie ")]/following-sibling::*[1][name()="td"]');
```